# What is the oldest version of firefox on IOS that supports css grid layout?

Tags: css, firefox, browser, css-grid, grid-layout

I managed to get information about versions supporting CSS grid layouts [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid). But it doesn't contain an entry for chrome/firefox on ios. I managed to find out the oldest supported version for chrome on IOS using the release notes but had hard luck finding the same for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You had the answer within reach, but just needed one piece of information to finally get there:

All web browsers on iOS, due to Apple's restrictions, are powered by [WebKit](https://webkit.org/), the same engine that powers iOS Safari.

Knowing this, we can look at the table on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) to determine that **the oldest version of iOS Firefox supporting CSS Grid is 10.3**.

---

*Source*: https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid

Comment: But, I want to know the version of Firefox that is equivalent to(started supporting grid) safari 10.3 because firefox releases follow their own version different from safari. The request user agent for firefox ios is Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) FxiOS/22.0  Mobile/15E148 Safari/605.1.15 and the version for firefox here is 22.0. The latest version of safari is still at 13.x